# How to random flip binary bit of char in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

If I have a char array `A`, I use it to store hex

```
A = "0A F5 6D 02"   size=11
```

The binary representation of this char array is:

```
00001010 11110101 01101101 00000010
```

I want to ask is there any function can random flip the bit?

That is:
if the parameter is 5

```
00001010 11110101 01101101 00000010   
-->

10001110 11110001 01101001 00100010
```

it will random choose 5 bit to flip.

I am trying make this hex data to binary data and use bitmask method to achieve my requirement. Then turn it back to hex. I am curious is there any method to do this job more quickly?

Sorry, my question description is not clear enough. In simply, I have some hex data, and I want to simulate bit error in these data. For example, if I have 5 byte hex data:

```
"FF00FF00FF"
```

binary representation is

```
"1111111100000000111111110000000011111111"
```

If the bit error rate is 10%. Then I want to make these 40 bits have 4 bits error. One extreme random result: error happened in the first 4 bit:

```
"0000111100000000111111110000000011111111"
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what means "random choose 5 bit"?

Comment: please show us some code that declares/defines the A char array

Comment: Can the same bit be flipped more than once? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: For example, if I have a 100 byte hex data. There will have 100*8 bits in binary representation. I want to make random 10% of these bits 0->1 or 1->0. 10% is my parameter. And array A --> char A[]="0A F5 6D 02";

Comment: No, one bit only change at most one time.

Comment: Have you considered `std::bitset` ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, find out which char the bit represents:

param is your bit to flip...

```
char *byteToWrite = &A[sizeof(A) - (param / 8) - 1];
```

So that will give you a pointer to the char at that array offset (-1 for 0 array offset vs size)

Then get modulus (or more bit shifting if you're feeling adventurous) to find out which bit in here to flip:

```
*byteToWrite ^= (1u << param % 8);
```

So that should result for a param of 5 for the byte at `A[10]` to have its 5th bit toggled.

Comment: I read the question as starting from the right, and you have read it as being from the left... which is understandable, as the bit 5 in from either end in the worked binary example is set:

`00001010 11110101 01101101 00000010` vs `10001110 11110001 01101001 00100010`

Either way though hopefully it will be plenty to help this chap out.

Comment: Sizeof(A) is will return you '4' always.Whatever may be number of array elements,that's what I am trying to point out.

Comment: The question stated A is an array - not a char* - sizeof (char[11]) will return 11.

Comment: Try it - sizeof (char*) will return the size of the local pointer (usually 4 on a 32 bit machine or 8 on a 64 bit machine). sizeof(A) where char[11] A = {0x01, .... etc}; will return 11.

Comment: Yes,I realized that,sorry.

Answer (score 1):

1. store the values of 2^n in an array
2. generate a random number seed
3. loop through x times (in this case 5) and go data ^= stored_values[random_num]

Alternatively to storing the 2^n values in an array, you could do some bit shifting to a random power of 2 like:

```
data ^= (1<<random%7)
```

Reflecting the first comment, you really could just write out that line 5 times in your function and avoid the overhead of a for loop entirely.

Comment: you don't need to loop if you do *(array + n), where n is the n-th byte in the array (assuming it's a `char` array)

Answer (score 0):

1. Take mod 8 of input(5%8)
2. Shift `0x80` to right by input value (e.g 5)
3. XOR this value with (input/8)th element of your character array.

code:

```
void flip_bit(int bit)
{
    Array[bit/8]  ^= (0x80>>(bit%8));
}
```

Comment: what's Ex-OR? only heard of XOR or Exclusive OR :)

Comment: The operator for Ex-OR in C is "^" (a^b).

Comment: ohh, I call it Ex-OR(Exclusive OR) sorry.

Answer (score 0):

1. First randomly chose x positions (each position consist of array index and the bit position).
2. Now if you want to flip i<sup>th</sup> bit from right for a number **n**. Find the remainder of `n` by **2<sup>n</sup>** as :

code:

```
int divisor = (2,i);
int remainder = n % divisor;
int quotient = n / divisor;
remainder = (remainder == 0) ? 1 : 0; // flip the remainder or the i th bit from right. 

n = divisor * quotient + remainder;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 32 bit number. You can treate the bits as parts of hte number and just xor this number with some random 5-bits-on number.

```
int count_1s(int )
{
  int m = 0x55555555;
  int r = (foo&m) + ((foo>>>1)&m);
  m = 0x33333333;
  r = (r&m) + ((r>>>2)&m);
  m = 0x0F0F0F0F;
  r = (r&m) + ((r>>>4)&m);
  m = 0x00FF00FF;
  r = (r&m) + ((r>>>8)&m);
  m = 0x0000FFFF;
  return r = (r&m) + ((r>>>16)&m);
}

void main()
{
   char input[] = "0A F5 6D 02";
   char data[4] = {};
   scanf("%2x %2x %2x %2x", &data[0], &data[1], &data[2], &data[3]);
   int *x = reinterpret_cast<int*>(data);
   int y = rand();
   while(count_1s(y) != 5)
   {
      y = rand(); // let's have this more random
   }
   *x ^= y;
   printf("%2x %2x %2x %2x" data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to convert the entire string back and forth from and to hex notation. Just pick a random character out of the hex string, convert this to a digit, change it a bit, convert back to hex character.

In plain C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main (void)
{
    char *hexToDec_lookup = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    char hexstr[] = "0A F5 6D 02";

    /* 0. make sure we're fairly random */
    srand(time(0));

    /* 1. loop 5 times .. */
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        /* 2. pick a random hex digit
              we know it's one out of 8, grouped per 2 */
        int hexdigit = rand() & 7;
        hexdigit += (hexdigit>>1);

        /* 3. convert the digit to binary */
        int hexvalue = hexstr[hexdigit] > '9' ? hexstr[hexdigit] - 'A'+10 : hexstr[hexdigit]-'0';

        /* 4. flip a random bit */
        hexvalue ^= 1 << (rand() & 3);

        /* 5. write it back into position */
        hexstr[hexdigit] = hexToDec_lookup[hexvalue];

        printf ("[%s]\n", hexstr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

<sup>It *might* even be possible to omit the convert-to-and-from-ASCII steps -- flip a bit in the character string, check if it's still a valid hex digit and if necessary, adjust.</sup>